# Anaconda install Orfeotoolbox

Tags: installation, orfeo-toolbox, anaconda

I am trying to install Orfeotoolbox as a package within one of my conda environments.
No matter which version of python I have (3.6 , 3.7 , 3.8) the package can not be installed.
Below is the result of installetion attempt:

[image]

Are there any other ways to install OTB with anaconda other than the one [here](https://anaconda.org/orfeotoolbox/otb) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `conda create` command, you should use `--channel` instead of `-channel` and it will be fine:

```
conda create -n pyOTB --channel orfeotoolbox --channel conda-forge otb
```

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. Yes I managed to creat the pyOTB environment, however when inside the pyOTB environment I run python and try to import OTB it does not recognize it ! My command is : " import otbApplication as otb". As the matter of fact there is no package name orfeo inside this environment! I would appreciate your comments on it.

Comment: Maybe you were not using the right python interpreter from the virtual environment. After environment activation, run the command `which python` to see if the python interpreter really is from conda (should be a path such as `~/miniconda3/bin/python`)

Comment: Yes the interpreter seems to be the good one : "~/anaconda3/envs/pyOTB/bin/python
". The ImportError seems to be related to a shared object file !                                            ImportError: libnsl.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: I guess it doesn't work on your OS then, I don't know why... On Ubuntu it is working fine for me

Comment: It's a pity! I use Fedora.